# Trim XML with nested recurring element type at different levels

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to maintain the structure of the XML document but just remove all `detail` elements that don't have a specified ID (in the following example I just want to keep `id="1"`.  The code example only goes three levels (A, B, C), but assume that the code pattern could go on indefinitely.  Is there an xpath I could use on the XML to trim out all `detail` elements not matching an id while maintaining the tree?

**Input**

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
            <details id="2">...</details>
        </C>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
            <details id="2">...</details>
        </C>
        <details id="1">...</details>
        <details id="2">...</details>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
            <details id="2">...</details>
        </C>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
            <details id="2">...</details>
        </C>
        <details id="1">...</details>
        <details id="2">...</details>
    </B>
    <details id="1">...</details>
    <details id="2">...</details>
</A>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
        </C>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
        </C>
        <details id="1">...</details>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
        </C>
        <C>
            <details id="1">...</details>
        </C>
        <details id="1">...</details>
    </B>
    <details id="1">...</details>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details[not(@id='1')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes the removed `details` elements do not have any children you want to keep.

Comment: `not(@id='1')` is generally written `@id != "1"`

Comment: @Borodin The two expressions are not equivalent. Add an element with no `id` attribute to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward with a proper XML parser

This program uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). It simply parses the XML file, uses an XPath expression to find all `details` elements that have an id other than 1 and deletes them, and then prints the result

The input XML file is expected as a parameter on the command line

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Twig;

my ($xml_file) = @ARGV;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile($xml_file);

$_->delete for $twig->findnodes('//details[@id != 1]');

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print;
```

#### output

```xml
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <details id="1">...</details>
    </C>
    <C>
      <details id="1">...</details>
    </C>
    <details id="1">...</details>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C>
      <details id="1">...</details>
    </C>
    <C>
      <details id="1">...</details>
    </C>
    <details id="1">...</details>
  </B>
  <details id="1">...</details>
</A>
```